# How to handle repositories/interfaces with controller inheritance in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, oop, interface, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having an issue with using repositories/interfaces in my controllers. My app is using Laravel 4.

My current controller inheritance tree is:

```
 +- BaseController
     +- FrontendController
         +- ProductController
```

In the `FrontendController` I am getting/setting some things to use across the board in my controllers, so I have set the interfaces in the constructor like so:

```
class FrontendController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(SystemRepositoryInterface $system,
                                BrandRepositoryInterface $brands,
                                CategoryRepositoryInterface $categories)
```

However, this now means I'm having to send through the interfaces (again) in all of my child controllers like so:

```
class ProductController extends FrontendController
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(SystemRepositoryInterface $system,
                                BrandRepositoryInterface $brands,
                                CategoryRepositoryInterface $categories,
                                ProductRepositoryInterface $products)
    {
        parent::__construct($system, $brands, $categories);
```

I'm new to this level/area of PHP but it feels wrong, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I would recommend you to use the IoC container with the [automatic resolution](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#automatic-resolution)

Comment: How much would it hurt (performance) to just add the `ProductRepositoryInterface` to  the FrontendController constructor and skip the constructor in the ProductController?

Comment: @RobGordijn that's what I was wondering because technically you could just 'preload' all of your repositories via the `FrontendController`

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not wrong. PHP does not support method overloading like other languages. So you have to rewrite the constructor of your `FrontendController` every time (Bro tip: A good IDE should help you a lot here ;>).
Laravel resolves all of the controllers constructor dependencies via its IoC-Container. Just add

```
App::bind('SystemRepositoryInterface', function() {
    return new EloquentSystemRepository();
});
```

for every repository in one of the bootstrap files of your application. And the framework will do the injection for you.

Comment: I might have to crack open the PHPStorm! I'm binding my interfaces to my repositories via: `App::bind('\Models\Interfaces\ProductRepositoryInterface',  '\Models\Repositories\DbProductRepository');
` - which I believe it similar to what you've shown in your example?

Comment: Yeah this is nearly the same, but the closure way is a little bit more performant because it doesn't need that much reflection.